# Проблема с кавычками

Tags: php, html

Вот столкнулась с проблемой: 
Например есть такой код:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description_text ?>">
```

Если в переменной `$description_text`, есть символ `"`, то, естественно, происходит некорректный вывод.
Я вижу только одно решение: перед выводом $description_text`проверять переменную на наличие символа`"` и ставить перед ним слэш ( `\` ).
Есть ли другой выход?

Comment: [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php) ,
[htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: http://www.php.su/functions/?addslashes

Answer (score 2):

*<sup>Вынесенные ссылки из комментариев</sup>*

Вам могут пригодиться следующие функции:

### [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

> (PHP 4, PHP 5)
>   `htmlspecialchars` — Преобразует специальные символы в
>   HTML-сущности

### [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlentities.php):

> (PHP 4, PHP 5)
>   `htmlentities` — Преобразует все возможные символы в
>   соответствующие HTML-сущности

### [`addslashes`](http://www.php.su/functions/?addslashes):

> (PHP 3, PHP 4, PHP 5)
>   `addslashes` — Экранирует спецсимволы в строке